# Twitter library for smalltalk

Tags: twitter, smalltalk

I am new to smalltalk. I have some experience in java and I am looking forward to develop a twitter client in smalltalk (pharo environment). I have done this in java with the twitter4j library but I really have no clue about how to proceed with the same in smalltalk.

Is there a twitter library available for the smalltalk platform? Would polymorph be a good choice to develop the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is OAuth implementation in cloudfork project that might come handy:

http://blog.doit.st/2011/02/15/cloudforksso-openid-and-oauth-support-for-smalltalk/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at http://code.google.com/p/twitter-client/downloads/list or http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/blog/blogView?entry=3448685967

While you're at it, it would be a good idea to put the code of a Twitter library on Squeaksource, with a Metacello configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Pier-Twitter package in http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/pier2addons. It is dedicated to Pier, but you should be able to extract what you want.

Regarding, the graphical library to develop the client, you have multiple choices. For the desktop, you may choose Polymorph. Also, you may want to have a look at Glamour which might be simpler to use (http://www.moosetechnology.org/tools/glamour). For the web, I would either choose Seaside or Aida/Web.